# Preloader and content div can be seen together for a short time: how to prevent?

Tags: jquery

This is my html structure:

```
<div class="content">
<!-- Pre Loading... -->
<div id="loadingMask" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    margin-top: 0px; width: inherit; height: inherit;">
    <img src="images/loading.gif" width="300px">
</div>

<!-- BEGIN: HTML for infos -->

<div id="infopanel"></div>
<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

<!-- END: HTML for infos -->
```

My code is this:

```
$("#infopanel").hide();
...making ajax request and populating infopanel div with results
$("#loadingMask").fadeOut("slow"); 
$("#infopanel").fadeIn("slow");
```

what happens is that for a brief moment user can see both loadingMask at the top of the page and my populated infopanel div at the bottom. After this brief moment just infopanel is visible that is what I want. However I don't like this effect.
How can I disable it?

Comment: Do you want to disable the fade effect or do you want to hide loadingMask entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callbacks like this:

```
$("#loadingMask").fadeOut("slow", function(){
   $("#infopanel").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

This way, `infopanel` will start fading in only when `loadingMask` is done fading out.